# Changing from web site to web project: issue with implementing ConfigurationSection

Tags: asp.net, configuration, configuration-management

I am using the ASP.NET Web Site Small Business Starter Kit as a starting point for a simple web app. I wanted to convert it to a web project from a web site for few reasons (better interaction with VisualSVN, etc..). I created a new ASP.NET Web Application from scratch... then copied and pasted all the files via explorer, then did project->create web application. There was some initial errors that I fixed, but now I get this on the original 'items' page:

An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for SmallBusinessDataProviders: Type 'FooWeb.ProviderSettingsValidation' does not inherit from 'System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler'. (C:\Projects\FooWebFacing\FooWeb\FooWeb\web.config line 5)

Does anyone know why it's giving me this error message that I have to implement IConfigurationSectionHandler? It worked without issue in the ASP.NET Web Site project by just inheriting from ConfigurationSection... And that website was build as .NET 3.5. I tried changing my project to even .NET 2.0 but still no luck - but I don't see how that matters anyway. I am using VS 2008 Developer Edition. Thanks very much for any help.

***EDIT: Just to be clear: the same exact code works fine as a web project - but not as a web application. This error makes no sense at all either, regardless of what project its from. Does anyone have any clue how this could happen?***